# count number of lines of a file in java, using random access file

Tags: java, file, line

Is there a way to count the number of lines in a file, in java, if the file was declared as a random access file?
I was thinking of sth like:

```
while(stop_condition)
{String str=file.readLine();
 count++;
 }
```

But i can't find in the random access file documentation, what could be in this case the stop_condition. Could you please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation was the first result in google: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Here's what it says to do:

```
while(file.readLine() != null)
  count++;
```

Comment: That would skip the content of the first line.

Comment: The question asks for the number of lines, so while the line isn't `null`, count it. Thats what this does. No skips

Answer (score 1):

`file.readLine()` will return null when you reach the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = null;

while ((line = file.readLine() != null) {
     // Do something :)
}
```